# XCODE AppelScript ObjC : set a variable

Tags: xcode, variables, applescript, applescript-objc

```
property parent : class "NSObject"

    -- IBOutlets
    property theWindow : missing value
    set value1 to :value number 1

on buttonClick_(sender)
         set the clipboard to value1
    end buttonClick_
```

I'm very lost with the way Xcode is handling variable. My variable are reported not defined, I figured out that this is actually not the case when I set the variable in a "sender"

but what If I want to use a variable outside a button/sender ? or what if I want to use the same variable in two different buttons.

I have the feeling that what I'm asking not making much sense but hopefully someone will get me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like in Objective-C or Swift:

Either declare a property with a default value:

```
property value1 : 1
```

Or declare the property without a value and set the value **in a handler**:

```
property value1 : missing value

...

on applicationDidFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
   set value1 to 1
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_
```

AppleScript code must always run in a handler. Even in a simple compiled script if you write code on the top level of the script the compiler wraps the code in the implicit `on run` handler.